# Make this easier

Tags: delphi, colors, label

How can I simplify this in Delphi?

```
Procedure colori1
Begin

 if Temperatura<=15 then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clBlue;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=16) and (Temperatura<=18) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clAqua;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=19) and (Temperatura<=22) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clLime;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=23) and (Temperatura<=26) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clYellow;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=27) and (Temperatura<=29) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
 end;

 if Temperatura>=30 then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clRed;
 end;
end;
```

If I use "for cycle" like this:

```
For i:=0 to n do label[i].font.color:=clRed
```

I'll obviously get an error, because Delphi doesn't know what `label[i]` means. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a more proper site for this?

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry, I was too hasty to post and I don't know about code review. I'll delete this and post it to Core Review. Thanks.

Comment: @Drift89 I made that question towards the Stack Overflow users as a whole, not towards you. I really don't know which is a best fit for your question. It might be that it is here. Please don't take my previous comment personally.

Comment: @Renan No problem ;) 
David Great suggestion! Now I try

Comment: Problem is that now we have an identical question in two places, with an identical answer in both places. Hmm, what to do.

Comment: @TLama It would be nice if we could write `<16` in a case statement wouldn't it?!!

Comment: @David, I can't imagine the notation. Maybe like `..16` ? `<16` doesn't fit me visually there.

Comment: @TLama What's wrong with `<16` or `<=15`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a review of working code.

Answer (score 11):

Declare a local variable to hold the color:

```
var
  Color: TColor;
```

Then decide what the color should be:

```
if Temperatura <= 15 then
  Color := clBlue
else if Temperatura <= 18 then
  Color := clAqua;
else ...
```

Then assign the color to the controls:

```
Form1.Label1.Font.Color := Color;
Form1.Label2.Font.Color := Color;
....
```

The labels could be stored in an array or a list. So that you can iterate over them to assign the color. You could declare the array like this, in the form class:

```
FLabels: TArray<TLabel>;
```

In the constructor assign it like this:

```
FLabels := TArray<TLabel>.Create(Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5);
```

To iterate over it setting the color do this:

```
var
  lbl: Tlabel;
....
for lbl in FLabels do
  lbl.Font.Color := Color;
```

You appear to be using a global variable `Form1`. Your code will be better without that global variable, and having this procedure (and others like it) converted into a method of the form.

Comment: Note to OP: The `TArray<>` recommendation requires a version of Delphi which comes with Generics, based on the question I'm not sure what version is being used. I believe version 2010+ supports it.

Comment: The chained if then else could be exchanged for a case statement, too.

Comment: @Gloegg the < and the > make that case statement exceedingly messy

Comment: @David, what's messy on what I wrote below ? Yes, it deserves comments since it's not clear on the first view, but I hate to read chained `if`s.

Comment: I take the ifs over the case, especially if you look at the if in my latest edit. On the other hand, take a look at the edit I'm about to make to your deleted answer ....

Comment: @David, I've been thinking of the same when we were talking about `<16` notation. To make it even "faster" one might define constants for those limit values. See my edit...

Comment: @TLama That's better still. The problem in my eyes is the duplication. When you write `..X` you have to follow it with `X+1..` on the next line. So I still like the `if` because you specify each dividing point once only.

Comment: @David You gain a bit of safety because the compiler checks, if you have an overlapping value in a case-statement, that's not the case with chained if's. It's a tiny advantage at the price of duplication.

Comment: @TLama I'm thinking of the time when you write `16..18` and then `20.22`. No safety there. On the other hand, the `if` is bullet proof.

Comment: @David, I can't see anything safer on your approach. You can forget one `if` statement and all the values of that missing statement range will fall back to the next statement as well as I can forget a range in my `case` conditions. You must have precise order of your conditions, I don't. If you were using approach with the fixed range (`if (X >= 16) and (X <= 18) then`) you wouldn't have a range overlap check. I have. I still feel a little bit safer with `case`.

Comment: @TLama I just prefer to avoid the duplication.